# Difference between ".Release()" and "->Release()" for CComPtr?

Tags: c++, com, atl

Can someone explain clearly what is the difference between 
`.Release()` 
and 
`->Release()` on a CComPtr ?

To be precise how the memory management happens in either case?

Comment: @tartanllama Too bad the most up-voted answer in the duplicate leads with such an imprecise statement.

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate duplicate, in this case they are both overloaded operators

Comment: Wow, most of those answers completely ignore operator overloading.

Comment: Simply step in with debugger into `CComPtr::Release` and you will immediately see a few lines of code that stand between further call to `IUnknown::Release` on the managed pointer.

Comment: ->Release() is almost certainly a bug, .Release() is something you should not do since the point of using CComPtr is to let it take care of it automatically.  Favor the `delete` operator instead, it is unambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

The `operator->` function of `CComPtr` yields a raw interface pointer to the object being managed. (but see below)

So, calling `->Release()` will release the object (i.e. decrement its internal reference count).

The `.Release()` function will call `->Release()`, *and* make the smart pointer stop managing the raw interface pointer.

The latter is usually what you want to do. If you call `->Release()` then smart pointer doesn't know this , and when the smart pointer's destructor runs, it will call `->Release()` again which is bad (double release).

According to [this page](http://www.369o.com/data/books/atl/0321159624/ch03lev1sec4.html), recent versions of ATL actually have `operator->` return a proxy class which hides `AddRef` and `Release`, so you should get a compilation error if you try `->Release()`, instead of getting a double delete.